# Kepler's Equation of Elliptical Motion in Terms of Cosine

Tags: numerical-methods, mathematical-astronomy

Virtually all material discussing Kepler's Equation of Elliptical Motion resolves its solution to solving the following equation numerically:

$$
E - \textit{e}\;\sin(E) = M
$$

where E is the Eccentric Anomaly,
*e* is the eccentricity,
and M is the Mean Anomaly.

In all the material I have read and sought out, never has a solution been stated in terms of cosine.

Other than the *naive* approach of simply writing the existing equation as
$$
E - \textit{e}\;\sqrt{1 -\cos^{2}(E)} = M
$$

is there an equation corresponding to the first one--but in terms of cosine?

Comment: Why should there be? You could just shift $E$ by $\frac\pi2$, there is no reason why the time origin should be at the periapsis. Some mix-up around this idea was discussed in https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/40700/solving-keplers-equation

Comment: Use the Kepler series and use $\sin(x)=\cos(pi/2-x)$?